# Variance of sum of random variables via conditional expectation.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, variance, covariance

Consider a sequence of random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, ..., X_n$, with $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = 0$ and $ \mathbb{E}[X_i^2] = \sigma^2 $, for all $ i = 1,2,...,n $. Let $\mathcal{F}_t := \sigma (X_1, X_2, ..., X_i)$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_1, X_2, ..., X_i$.

Now I want to compute $\mathbb{E} [ (\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^2 ]$ using the language of conditional expectations, and I find something awkward. Perhaps it's just I'm missing something trivial.

Here it goes. By definition of variance and the tower law of total expectation, we have
\begin{align}
& \mathbb{E} \left[ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right)^2 \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[  \mathbb{E} \left[ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right)^2 | \mathcal{F}_{n-1} \right] \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[  \mathbb{E} \left[  X_n^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_n X_i + \sum_{i,j<n} X_i X_j | \mathcal{F}_{n-1} \right] \right]
\end{align}
For $i < n$, $ \mathbb{E} [ X_n X_i | \mathcal{F}_{n-1} ] = 0$, since $X_i$ is effectively a constant given the information in $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$.

Thus we have
\begin{align}
&\mathbb{E} \left[ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right)^2 \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[  \mathbb{E} \left[  X_n^2 + \sum_{i,j<n} X_i X_j | \mathcal{F}_{n-1} \right] \right] = \sigma^2 + \mathbb{E} \left[  \mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i \right)^2 | \mathcal{F}_{n-1} \right] \right] \\=&  \sigma^2 +  \mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i \right)^2  \right].
\end{align}

Inductively, we get $ \mathbb{E} \left[ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right)^2 \right] = n \sigma^2 $.
The covariance terms all disappear! Why? Which step went wrong?

Comment: If the random variables are not independent $\mathbb{E}[X_n| \mathcal{F}_{n-1}] \neq \mathbb{E}[X_n]$, in general. If the random variables are independent, then $\mathbb{E}[X_n| \mathcal{F}_{n-1}] = \mathbb{E}[X_n]= 0$, which yields $n \sigma^2$ as the answer, as expected.

Comment: $\mathbb{E} [ (\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^2 ]= \mathrm{Var}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) -(\sum_{i=1}^n   \mathbb{E} [X_i])^2$ which from independence and zero mean here is $n\sigma^2$ as you have found another way

Comment: @sudeep5221 Thanks! Can't believe I missed that.